# VBScript automating Visio: How to move dynamic glue to another shape?

Tags: vbscript, visio

I am currently triying to automate Visio by using VBScripts.

I have a visio shape "Start" having an existing connect "Verbindung" pointing to "BeginX" and targeting to "PosX" (therefore having a dynamic end).

I do NOT manage to modify the dynamic end, so that it is glued to shape "Stop". :(

Is there a way to move an existing connector so that the shapes are connected successfully?

[image]

```
Set startShape = CreateShape(visioApp,"ProzessSchablone.vss","Start",1,10)
Set stopShape = CreateShape(visioApp,"ProzessSchablone.vss","Stop",3,10)
Set startConnectedFrom = startShape.FromConnects.Item(1)    'to retrieve value: connect
```

Something like that does not work:

```
startConnectedFrom.Cells("BeginX").glueToPos stopShape,0.5,0.5
```

Also I tried for "PosX" instead of "BeginX", does not work as well. :(

Could anyone help me on that please?

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be getting the shape reference from the Connect object you've retrieved.  So how about something like this:

```
Set shpConn = shpStart.FromConnects(1).FromSheet
Dim vFromCellStop As Cell
Set vFromCellStop = shpConn.CellsU("EndX")    
vFromCellStop.GlueToPos shpStop, 0.5, 0.5
```

If you're using Visio 2007 on then you might find it simpler to delete the original connector and use the [AutoConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff765915.aspx) method on the Shape object.  If you're looking at a previous version or specifically want to deal with which cells glues to which then Connects and FromConnects are better.

Here's a couple of VBA examples of both methods:

```
Sub AutoConnectExample()
Dim shpStart As Shape
Dim shpStop As Shape
Dim vPag As Page

    Set vPag = ThisDocument.Pages(1)

    Set shpStart = vPag.Drop(ThisDocument.Masters("Start"), 1, 3)
    Set shpStop = vPag.Drop(ThisDocument.Masters("Stop"), 3, 1)

    shpStart.AutoConnect shpStop, visAutoConnectDirNone

End Sub



Public Sub ConnectWithGlueExample()

Dim shpStart As Shape
Dim shpStop As Shape
Dim vPag As Page
Dim shpConn As Shape

    Set vPag = ThisDocument.Pages(1)

    Set shpStart = vPag.Drop(ThisDocument.Masters("Start"), 5, 7)
    Set shpStop = vPag.Drop(ThisDocument.Masters("Stop"), 7, 5)

    Set shpConn = vPag.Drop(Application.ConnectorToolDataObject, 1, 1)

    Dim vFromCellStart As Cell
    Dim vToCellStart As Cell
    Set vFromCellStart = shpConn.CellsU("BeginX")
    Set vToCellStart = shpStart.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, 0)

    Dim vFromCellStop As Cell
    Dim vToCellStop As Cell
    Set vFromCellStop = shpConn.CellsU("EndX")
    Set vToCellStop = shpStop.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, 0)

    vFromCellStart.GlueTo vToCellStart
    vFromCellStop.GlueTo vToCellStop

End Sub
```

If you run these two you should get the following results (note - no error checking and assumes the masters exist in the document you're calling the code from):

[image: Visio shape connections]

Comment: Hi John,

thanks sooo much for your help - your first solution works perfectly! 
I also tried with the autoconnect - but then there was always a new connection along to the existing connection "Verbindung" created. 
But now it works, thank you!! :)

Cheers -
Doris